# Environment `MiniWorld-PickupObjects` doesn't exist

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm working on an RL project where I need to try my idea on miniworld environment. After installing the gymnasium and miniworld, when I tried to load the environment it shows the following error,

[image]

How can I get rid of this error and load miniworld environment? This is additional info that I'm working on a cluster. I don't know if this is valuable info to solve the problem as I could able to load the environment locally on my machine.

A minimal reproducible code is attached below,

```
import gymnasium
env = gymnasium.make('MiniWorld-PickupObjects-v0')#, 
render_mode='human', domain_rand=False)
for i_episode in range(50):
  env.reset()
  done = False
  episode_Step = 0
  while not done:
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    next_state, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)
    done = terminated + truncated
    env.render()
env.close()
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Also, see [MCVE]. `MiniWorld-PickupObjects` and `MiniWorld-PickupObjects-v0` is not the same. Could this be the issue?

Comment: I have added a minimal reproducible code. I tried the potential solution you mentioned, Unfortunately, it is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To get avaliable envs:

```
print(gymnasium.envs.registry.keys())
```

Which outputs these on a fresh install:

```
CartPole-v0
CartPole-v1
MountainCar-v0
MountainCarContinuous-v0
Pendulum-v1
Acrobot-v1
phys2d/CartPole-v0
phys2d/CartPole-v1
phys2d/Pendulum-v0
LunarLander-v2
LunarLanderContinuous-v2
BipedalWalker-v3
BipedalWalkerHardcore-v3
CarRacing-v2
Blackjack-v1
FrozenLake-v1
FrozenLake8x8-v1
CliffWalking-v0
Taxi-v3
tabular/Blackjack-v0
tabular/CliffWalking-v0
Reacher-v2
Reacher-v4
Pusher-v2
Pusher-v4
InvertedPendulum-v2
InvertedPendulum-v4
InvertedDoublePendulum-v2
InvertedDoublePendulum-v4
HalfCheetah-v2
HalfCheetah-v3
HalfCheetah-v4
Hopper-v2
Hopper-v3
Hopper-v4
Swimmer-v2
Swimmer-v3
Swimmer-v4
Walker2d-v2
Walker2d-v3
Walker2d-v4
Ant-v2
Ant-v3
Ant-v4
Humanoid-v2
Humanoid-v3
Humanoid-v4
HumanoidStandup-v2
HumanoidStandup-v4
GymV21Environment-v0
GymV26Environment-v0
```

Which doesn't contain `MiniWorld-PickupObjects-v0` or `MiniWorld-PickupObjects`.

According to the [doc](https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/registry/#gymnasium.register)s, you have to register a new env to be able to use it with `gymnasium.make()`. So either register a new env or use any of the envs listed above.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
pip install minigrid
```

then

```py
import gymnasium
import minigrid
env = gymnasium.make('MiniWorld-PickupObjects-v0')#,
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This won't work in clusters.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured out from the MiniWorld Github page to run the script as follows,

```
xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 1024x768x24 -ac +extension GLX +render -noreset" python3 your_script.py
```

This is when the script is running in Cluster. Otherwise simple run would work. This method will also work in sbatch as well.

To run in interactive, x11 forwarding can also employed.